# Data to put in a collection?

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

Tell me how to make a list of items and find the specified number ? Do with selenide.

```
ElementsCollection resultElements = $$(By.className("result-table"));
```

Here I put the whole table. The table contains the EIS numbers, they must be selected. EIS(31908403282), here is the HTML:

```
<div class="column-main__header-item">
        <h6>
            Номер ЕИС
        </h6>
        <p>
           <a href="regNumber=31908403282" class="purchase-card" 
            target="_blank">31908403282
           </a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="column-main__header-item">
        <h6>Номер на площадке</h6>
        <p>4421/ЗКТЭ-РЖДС/19</p>
    </div>
```

If search Refine through findElement and search by tag:

```
ElementsCollection resultElements = $$(By.className("column-main__header-item")).findElement(tagName("a")).getText();
```

it says error:

> "cannot find symbol symbol: method findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)
>   location: class com.codeborne.selenide.ElementsCollection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all **purchase-card**s use `a.purchase-card` css selector or `.result-table a.purchase-card`:

```
ElementsCollection purchaseCards = $$("a.purchase-card");
System.out.println(purchaseCards.texts());
```

`$$()` is a `List<SelenideElement>` and you cannot use `findElement` here.
**Wrong**: `$$(By.className("column-main__header-item")).findElement(tagName("a")).getText();`

**Correct**: `$$(By.className("column-main__header-item")).first().findElement(tagName("a")).getText();`

**Correct by index**: `$$(By.className("column-main__header-item")).get(5).findElement(tagName("a")).getText();`

Comment: Since there were two identical classes, there was a difficulty in correctly specifying the selector. Experimenting I got a working function:  ElementsCollection headerItem = $$(".result-table .column-main__header-item > p > a");
        for (SelenideElement number : headerItem) {
            System.out.println(number.getText());
        }  Thanks for your help !